# R: Error in heatmap(data) : 'x' must be a numeric matrix. Which 'x' is it referring to?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a heatmap in R. This is my dataset:

```
Team, Att_L, Att_M, Att_R,
Aston Villa, 0.37, 0.24, 0.39
Birmingham City, 0.34, 0.26, 0.4
Blackburn Rovers, 0.38, 0.26, 0.36
Bolton Wanderers, 0.32, 0.27, 0.41
Brentford, 0.34, 0.28, 0.38
Bristol City, 0.37, 0.26, 0.37
Derby County, 0.34, 0.26, 0.4
Hull City, 0.38, 0.21, 0.41
Ipswich Town, 0.33, 0.24, 0.43
Leeds United, 0.37, 0.24, 0.39
Middlesbrough, 0.37, 0.25, 0.38
Millwall, 0.3, 0.24, 0.46
Norwich City, 0.36, 0.24, 0.4
Nottingham Forest, 0.37, 0.22, 0.41
Preston North End, 0.35, 0.26, 0.39
Queens Park Rangers, 0.35, 0.24, 0.41
Reading, 0.37, 0.23, 0.4
Rotherham United, 0.38, 0.27, 0.35
Sheffield United, 0.41, 0.21, 0.38
Sheffield Wednesday, 0.37, 0.29, 0.34
Stoke City, 0.36, 0.25, 0.39
Swansea City, 0.38, 0.24, 0.38
West Bromwich Albion, 0.38, 0.25, 0.37
Wigan Athletic, 0.38, 0.24, 0.38
```

It starts off as a tibble called Pitch_axis. I convert this to a table and use `gather()` to get the data ready for the heatmap.

```
 data2 <- as.data.table(gather(Pitch_axis, variable, value, Att_L:Att_R))
```

Then I try to run heatmap() on it:

```
 heatmap(data2)
```

This returns the error:

```
>Error in heatmap(data2) : 'x' must be a numeric matrix
```

I don't understand this from two directions: 1. I don't understand which variable is 'x' 2. I tried converting to a matrix and all the observations came out in double "", so presumably as strings.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: For the error message, see `?heatmap` and take a look at the first argument of the function. And for the second question: A matrix can only contain variables of a single type. Try `matrix(c(1, 2, "C"), 1)` and you'll see the first two elements will be coerced to characters, just like in your case (because of the Team column).

Answer (score 0):

Try this? Solely representative!

```
library(tidyverse)
df<-as.tibble(df)
df<-df %>% 
  gather("id","value",2:ncol(.))

df2<-matrix(df$value,4,8)


 heatmap(df2,labRow=df$Team,labCol = df$id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got this.

```
        ggplot(data2, aes(Team, variable)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value), color = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red") +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 10),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        plot.title = element_text(size=16),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  ggtitle("Attack more down left, right or centre?",
          subtitle = "") +
  labs(fill = "%age") +
coord_flip()
```